# Count the number of matched terms in a text file?

Tags: perl, unix, grep, match

I am trying to count the number of matched terms from an input list containing one term per line with a data file and create an output file containing the matched (grep'd) term with the number of matches.

The input_list.txt looks like this:

```
+ 5S_rRNA
+ 7SK
+ AADAC
+ AC000111.3
+ AC000111.6
```

The data.txt file:

```
chr10   101780038   101780209   5S_rRNA
chr10   103578280   103578430   5S_rRNA
chr10   112327234   112327297   5S_rRNA
chr10   120766459   120766601   7SK
chr10   127408228   127408317   7SK
chr10   127511874   127512063   AADAC
chr10   14614140    14614294    AC000111.3
chr10   14695964    14696146    AC000111.6
```

I would like to create an output file (output.txt) containing the matched terms with their corresponding count.

```
+ 5S_rRNA   3
+ 7SK   2
+ AADAC 1
+ AC000111.3    1
+ AC000111.6    1
```

So far, I've produced a list containing all the matched terms using the following script but all attempts to provide a count of the matched terms haven't worked.

```
    exec < input_list.txt
    while read line
    do
                grep -w data.txt | awk '{print $0}'| sort| uniq  >> grep_output.txt
    done
```

I have tried `grep -o -w | wc -l and grep -w data.txt | wc -l` etc but I can't work out how to produce an output list containing the matched term with its corresponding count.

Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can grep the words from the input.txt and use uniq to get the counts:

```
cut -d' ' -f2 input.txt | grep -o -f - data.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

*Gives:*

```
  3 5S_rRNA
  2 7SK
  1 AADAC
  1 AC000111.3
  1 AC000111.6
```

You can also add another sed to get formatted output:

```
cut -d' ' -f2 input.txt | grep -o -f - data.txt | sort | uniq -c | \
      sed 's/\s*\([0-9]*\)\s*\(.*\)/+ \2\t\1/'
```

*Produces:*

```
+ 5S_rRNA   3
+ 7SK   2
+ AADAC 1
+ AC000111.3    1
+ AC000111.6    1
```

Comment: +1. However, I'd have preferred using `paste` for the desired format.  Something like: `paste -d' ' input.txt <(cut -d' ' -f2 input.txt | grep -o -f - data.txt | uniq -c | awk '{print $1}')`

Comment: Moreover, the `sort` pipeline is probably useless here.

Answer (score 4):

`awk` can be good for this:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {vals[$2]=$2}
       $4 in vals {count[$4]++}
       END {for (i in count) print i, count[i]}' input_list data.txt
AC000111.3 1
AC000111.6 1
5S_rRNA 3
AADAC 1
7SK 2
```

#### Explanation

`vals[]` stores the second field of the `input_list` file. Then, it checks if the 4th field of the second file `data.txt` is in any line and counts the occurences in `count[]` array. Finally it prints the output in the `END{}` block.

Piping to `sort` with `n` (numeric) `r` (reverse) and `k2` (2nd column) options, you get sorted data:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {vals[$2]=$2}
       $4 in vals {count[$4]++}
       END {for (i in count) print i, count[i]}' input_list data.txt | sort -rnk2
5S_rRNA 3
7SK 2
AC000111.6 1
AC000111.3 1
AADAC 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this - which is probably what you were heading for yourself. It basically counts the number of matches using "wc -l" and then, if that is greater than zero, outputs the search string and the number of matches:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
   line=${line##+ }       # Strip off leading + and space
   n=$(grep "$line" data.txt 2> /dev/null | wc -l)
   if [ $n -gt 0 ]; then
      echo $line $n
   fi
done < input_list.txt
```

Comment: Stupid question but how do you print the output to a separate file? Thanks

Comment: Do two echoes... "echo $line" then on the next line "echo $n"

Comment: It's still printing to the screen

Comment: Add "> yourOutputFile" to the very end of the very last line.

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -lane '$s{ $F[3] }++ END{ print "+ $_ $s{$_}" for sort keys %s }' data.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in perl using hashes too:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict; 

open my $list, '<', 'in.txt' or die "$!";
open my $input, '<', 'in.2.txt' or die "$!";

my @split;
my (%data, %hash, %exists);
while(<$input>){
    chomp;
    @split = split(/\s+/);
    my ($info) = $split[3];
    $data{$info}++;
}

while (<$list>){
    chomp;
    my @split = split(/\+ /);
    my ($match) = $split[1];
    $hash{$match} = 1;
}

my $count = 0;
for my $compare (keys %hash){
    if (exists $data{$compare} ){
        $exists{$compare} = $data{$compare};        
        }
 }

foreach my $c (keys %exists){
    print "+ $c: $exists{$c}\n"
}
```

Output:

```
+ 5S_rRNA: 3
+ AADAC: 1
+ 7SK: 2
+ AC000111.6: 1
+ AC000111.3: 1
```